# sudo does not work with database stored users

Tags: linux, sudo, pam

I have set up pam and nss on a linux server (ubuntu 16.04) to get users and groups from a remote postgresql database. Login on the server is now fine, after i solved an issue that db-stored groups where not found.

But if i now try to sudo with an db-stored user, i get the error

```
ckel@sync1:~$ sudo -i
sudo: unknown uid: 1006
sudo: unable to initialise policy plug-in
```

The user is member of %admin, which is configured in /etc/sudoers

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

All local users can sudo as expected, but all db-stored users can't.

Edit: I added the following lines to the common-* files

```
auth        optional    pam_pgsql.so 
account     optional    pam_pgsql.so
password    required    pam_pgsql.so
session     optional    pam_mkhomedir.so
session     optional    pam_pgsql.so
```

Local and ssh-logins are fine

Comment: How did you setup PAM for this? Did you edit the `/etc/pam.d/common-*` files? What changes did you make?

Comment: You will also need to look at modifying /etc/pam.d/sudo taking the postgresql module into account.